# What happened to the flags?

Tags: discussion, flags

I was reading a long question (which was shown then as made 15 seconds ago). I wanted to flag the question but I didn't know which flag to use (because all the flag types were available). So I read the question again with attention. Then I knew which flag to use, but there was only one flag type left: "other - needs moderator attention". What happened to the other types of the flags?

Comment: Refresh the page. Was the question closed?

Comment: No, it isn't closed yet.

Comment: Link to question?

Comment: Uhm... it got deleted. My question is, why do flags disappear?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to flag a deleted question for any of the other reasons. "Needs moderator attention" is the fallback, always available. It is occasionally used on deleted questions, like if you deleted by accident and want a moderator to undelete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a question gets deleted, the only possible flag choice is "other". The flag dialog is loaded when the flag button is pressed, but the rest of the page doesn't update.